# Is there a way to programmatically update the list of authorized external testers (by email) for testflight

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I would like to know if it is possible to add and remove users (by email) from the list of authorized external users for testflight.

If so, where can I find documentation on how to do that?

Not manually, but automated.

Answer (score 0):

The [app store connect API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/prerelease_versions_and_beta_testers/beta_testers) can create and delete beta testers (i.e., Testflight users). You should study that documentation first, then come back with more questions if there are things you don't understand.